# Saving vim macros

Tags: vim, editor, macros

Does anyone know how to properly save/reuse macros recorded inside of a vim editor?

Answer (score 267, accepted):

Use `q` followed by a letter (for example 'x') to record a macro, then press `q` to end the macro definition. The pattern surrounded by the starting and ending `'q'` during this definition just goes into one of the copy/paste registers (in this case, register 'x') so you can paste it with the`"xp` or `"xP` commands in normal mode, where x is the register to paste. Typing `"xp` in normal mode inserts the contents in register x and exits back to normal mode.

To save it, you open up .vimrc and paste the contents while defining the macro using `let @x`, then the register will be around the next time you start vim.
The format is something like:

```
let @q = 'macro contents'
```

Be careful of quotes, though.  They would have to be escaped properly.

So to save a macro `'x'`, you can do:

- From normal mode: `qx`
- enter whatever commands
- From normal mode: `q`
- open .vimrc
- insert a line `let @x = '...'` (see the following)
- For the above `...` pattern, you can use `"xp` just at the place where the pattern should be placed. But this is not essential, you can just type in the macro definition.

Comment: Also, if you need to insert special characters (like escape, in my case) use `CTRL-V <ESC>` in insert mode to insert the correct character. A literal `<ESC>` doesn't work

Comment: "Note however, that the above method using :let will not work as expected for any macros which you make ending in a <CR> or <NL> character (carriage return or newline).". http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Macros#Saving_a_macro

Comment: Are the quotes (around macro contents) required?

Comment: `Ctrl+r Ctrl+r registerName` inputs register content without interpreting them - better than `"qp`. +1 for in-vim method nevertheless.

Comment: @adam_0 Could you elaborate on this? Perhaps, include an example? I can't figure out how to embed special characters, namely esc. I've tried every combination of inputting an escape to no avail. The "key code" ends up ruining the macro and the entire sequence gets printed.

Comment: @GH05T for example, if you have `:set expandtab` so that hitting the <tab> key inserts a number of spaces, you can type (from insert mode) `CTRL-V <TAB>` to insert an actual tab character.

Comment: For me, I have `let @l='/, <cr>ai'` in my _vimrc, but when I try "@l" it just puts "/, <cr>ai" into the command bar at the bottom, rather than executing it as a macro. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have MacOS 10.14.6 (Mojave) and I have found that recording macros using the 'q' results in the macro being persisted between sessions automatically.   Or yanking to a named buffer also results in the yanked contents being available to subsequent vim sessions.  I have found that the macros (or named buffers) are stored in ~/.viminfo.  I am using vim 8.0.

Comment: Hi all, I have had pressed '+1' for this long time ago but I couldn't exactly understand it today. So after some tests, I edited the answer to make it clearer and easier to understand!

Answer (score 24):

For a more robust solution you can checkout [Marvim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2154).

It lets you save a macro in a specific namespace (or use the filetype as a default namespace) and you can later search for your saved macros and load them in a register ready for use.

If you reuse a lot of macros, this is pretty helpful.

Comment: Just want to second this and say how easy it is to setup marvim- copy a single file to your /plugin directory, then use F3 to save a macro and F2 to run.

Answer (score 21):

Write your macros inside your ~/.vimrc, to define a macro launched by CTRL+O by example, add the following line to your ~/.vimrc :

```
map <C-O> MACROTEXT
```

when you record a macro by typing `qa` you can retrieve your macro text by typing `"ap`

Comment: Using "ap or equivalent didn't work, but you can get to the same info  by :reg

Comment: "ap would refer to a macro recorded on the `a` register

Answer (score 18):

You can do like this on your `~/.vimrc`

```
:let @a="iHello World!\<CR>bye\<Esc>"
```

NOTE: You must use double quotes to be able to use special keys like in `\<this silly example>`.

Comment: Thanks for this, saved me lots of headaches since my macro uses lots of ESC and the generated sequence for ESC key is something like `^[<80><fd>a`, and tricky to make it work w/ single quotes. This approach is simpler/easier, and should be emphasized in the docs.

Answer (score 13):

The `:mkexrc` (or `:mkvimrc`) command can be used to save all the current `:map` and `:set` settings to a file.  See `:help mkexrc` for details.

Answer (score 3):

Vim 8.0 on MacOS Mojave (10.14.6) actually persists macros and named buffers automatically (by default, although I haven't looked for a way of turning this behavior off).  Closing a Vim session will update the `~/.viminfo` file with any named buffers / macros.