# Replacing alternate line in vi text file with a particular string

Tags: vi

I have text file which consists of 5 columns , if i want to replace every alternate line in second column with particular string ,how can do this in vi text editor?

```
eg: 1 CG 54 76 76
    2 CG 45  78 78
    3 CG 48  76 89
    4 CG 49  50 52
```

if i want to replace 2 nd and 4 th line (2nd column) with CA how can i do this in vi text editor?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using vim, this is a simple macro. If you're not sure if you're using vim, then in command mode, type <kbd>qq</kbd> and check that you see *recording* in the status line at the bottom. If so, then you can use this macro.

Beginning on line 1, record the macro with: `qqj0wcwCA[Esc]jq`

This will edit the 2nd line and leave you on the 3rd line, and now you have the macro in register `q`. Type <kbd>100@q</kbd> to execute the command in register `q` 100 times.

Command details:

- Begin on Line 1
- **qq** - this begins recording a macro, you'll see *recording* in the status line at the bottom.
- **j** - moves to the next (alternate) line.
- **0** - moves to the beginning of the line.
- **w** - jumps to the next word (2nd column)
- **cwCA** - changes this word to *CA*.
- **Esc key** - leave edit mode.
- **j** - moves to the next line.
- **q** - this stops recording the macro.

Comment: How do you map and execute such a macro? (I'm sure this is something I could google)

Comment: to execute the macro use the _@_ key, followed by the register containing the macro - in the above answer we've used _q_. So, **@q** will execute the macro above. Precede _@q_ with a number _N_ to execute the macro N times, e.g.: **10@q**

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks! (I guess you may have already typed that, sorry)

Comment: also you **can** map a macro, though I've never had a good reason to do so. **:map :MyMacroName @q** for a macro in register _q_ as above. To keep such a mapped macro around, you'd need to persist the macro and the map in vimrc. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024443/saving-vim-macros