# How to create a macro with vim commands?

Tags: vim, macros

I am trying to create a macro to use it globaly. I have inserted this command to my *.vimrc* file

```
let @c='<esc>:r c.c'
```

or

```
let @c=':r c.c'
```

but in both cases when I use "**@c**" on any file it only **prints 'c>:r c.c'** on the the file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a '`^M`' at the end of your macro, then "`@c`" should work. Else '`:@c`' should work as mentioned by ebenezer. You should use <kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd></kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to insert '`^M`'.

```
let @c=':r c.c^M'
```

Best way would be to record the macro first and then save it to the `.vimrc`.
If these doesn't work, you can check the content of your register `c` using `"cp` and see if there is something missing.

Answer (score 0):

This is [described in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2024537/758011). Try something like this:

```
let @c = ':r c.c'
```

and then, in your file, use

```
:@c
```

to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include special characters in your macro (like Escape or Enter) then use a non-literal string (double quotes, not single quotes) and the correct syntax.  See `:help expr-string`.  You could use raw special characters, as @Amit suggests, but this will make your vimrc file hard to read.

Assuming that you are starting in Normal mode and want to type <kbd>@</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>, there is no need to start off with an Escape.

For testing purposes, I tried

```
:let @c = ":echo 'foo'\<CR>"
```

and it worked as expected.  I even added this line (without the leading <kbd>:</kbd>) to my vimrc file just to make sure, and tested it that way.  This should work:

```
:let @c = ":r c.c\<CR>"
```